# Terraform get a list of IDs from a resource created with count

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm defining a number of subnet resources:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnets" {
  count = 8
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(var.cidr_block, 3, count.index)
  vpc_id = var.vpc
}
```

I then have to pass a list of those subnet IDs to another resource. I know that the IDs are reachable on `aws_subnet.my_subnets[count].id`, but how do I loop through those and append all of the values to a list in order to pass it to the other resource?
The recommendation I've seen is to tag the subnets, then use a data attribute to look up those subnets, and they will be returned in a list format, but I have the IDs right there on the output of the resource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found what I was thinking of - splat expression: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html

Comment: Moved to https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html

Comment: I know you've linked to the relevant documentation, but I think its also helpful to have an answer here since as we've seen above, the link might change. `aws_subnet.my_subnets[*].id` will generate a list of id's.